# Rails - problems with comment implementation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, comments, form-for

I've some trouble with my Rails application. I have some video tutorials and I want to let the user write some comments. I've created 3 models: comment.rb, user.rb and tutorial.rb. Tutorial has many comments and belongs to user; comment belongs to tutorial and to user; user has many comments and many tutorials. I have the create action in tutorial_controller and it works. When the tutorial has been created, a view with a comment_form is rendered. At this point, the user can write his comment BUT when he submits I got a problem with the create action in the comments_controller. 
The message error is

**NoMethodError in CommentsController#create**

***undefined method `comments' for nil:NilClass***

Why 'comments' is undefined? Of course the comment is not created.
And now some code...

comment model:

```
   class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  #content may be tutorial, post etc. Body is the real content of the comment
  attr_accessible :writer, :content, :body

  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :tutorial
end
```

Create action in comments controller:

```
def create

    @comment = Comment.new
    @comment = @tutorial.comments.build(params[:comment])

    if @comment.save
      flash[:success] = 'Your comment was successfully added!'
      render 'tutorials/show'
    else
      render 'tutorials/show'
    end
  end
```

Comment form:

```
<%= form_for(@tutorial.comments.build(params[:id])) do |f| %>


    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :body %>
      <%= f.text_area :body, class: 'form-control', required: true %>
    </div>

    <%= f.submit class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
<% end %>
```

Show action in tutorials controller:

```
def show
    #shows the page of the single tutorial
    @tutorial = Tutorial.find(params[:id])
    current_tutorial = @tutorial
  end
```

Thanks!!

Comment: The error is because `@tutorial` is not initialised,so it throws error in this line  `@comment = @tutorial.comments.build(params[:comment])`

Comment: And also having this line `@comment = Comment.new` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: You have it in the `show` method but you don't have it in `create` method.

Comment: As you can see in show action I set the value of current tutorial as the tutorial we're seeing in the view but when we tried to put 
'@tutorial = current_tutorial' in the comments controller create action I got the same problem. Current tutorial is handled in session helper

Comment: Try adding `@tutorial = Tutorial.find(params[:id])` to your `create` method

Comment: I've tried but I got this error 'Couldn't find Tutorial without an ID'